# sql-query, find and replace with this particular code

Tags: sql, select, replace, union

I need to understand the following SQL query and would like to ask if anybody could explain it to me a bit more in detail (like the xml path) as well as update it with a replace element?
So I want to find all values with BlaBlaBlaBla and replace them with HaHaHaHa instead. At the moment the query is finding all values of BlaBlaBlaBla only.

```
DECLARE @searchstring  NVARCHAR(255)
SET @searchstring = '%BlaBlaBlaBla%'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @sql = STUFF((
  SELECT 
    ' UNION ALL SELECT ''' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AS tbl, ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS col, [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] AS val' + 
    ' FROM [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''' + @searchstring + ''''
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar', 'varchar', 'char', 'ntext') FOR XML PATH('')) ,1, 11, '')

Exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the XML PATH is a trick to get the strings to all concatenate together.

You could change it to `REPLACE` with something like this:

```
SELECT @sql = 
SELECT
    ' UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + '
      SET ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' = REPLACE(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ', ''' + @search_string + ''', ' + ', ''' + @replace_string + '''
      WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' LIKE ''' + @searchstring + ''''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE
    DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar', 'varchar', 'char', 'ntext') FOR XML PATH('')

EXEC(@sql)
```

Some caveats:

I haven't tested this. When you're generating code like this it's very easy to make minor errors with all of the start and end quotes, etc. I would print out the SQL and check it, repeating as necessary until you get the output SQL correct.

Also, this is generally not a good idea. If your database is large and/or has a large number of tables then performance is going to be miserable. You should usually do the analysis of where you think this sort of data is going to appear and write code that will correct it as necessary. The fact that data elements are buried in strings throughout your data is concerning.

Finally, be aware that this might easily update additional data that you didn't intend to update. If you try to update "123" with "456" and there's a string out there that is "My ID is 1234" it's going to become "My ID is 4564".

BTW, the `QUOTENAME` function is a way of enclosing your table and column names in `[` and `]`, but if the quote character is changed in a DB implementation it should still work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 


From your select, is every value everywhere in all tables selected? Is there an easier way to say find this value everywhere and replace it with something else?


Maybe the XML path is overkill if all I wanna do is replace the value everywhere. 




"Finally, be aware that this might easily update additional data that you didn't intend to update. If you try to update "123" with "456" and there's a string out there that is "My ID is 1234" it's going to become "My ID is 4564"." - This exactly what I want.

Comment: Replace the `EXEC(@sql)` with `SELECT @sql` and see what it returns to get an idea of how the code works. It is getting all of the string columns in the database and generating an update for each one to look for that string and replace it. Just off the top of my head, it's going to be very inefficient though because if a table has three string columns it's going to run three update statements and every one of them will have to do a full table scan.